# Angular showing data in table not in object

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am working on an Angular application with ngx-datatable installed and working.
I have a Supplier object and I need to display a table using ngx-datatable where some columns are showing some properties of the object and some columns are showing values calculated on the fly on object's properties.

This is my Supplier class:

```
import { Invoice } from '../../invoice/model/invoice';
import { MasterData } from '../../master-data/model/master-data';

export class Supplier {
    "createdAt": Date;
    "createdBy": string;
    "updatedAt": Date;
    "updatedBy": string;
    "id": string;
    "masterData": MasterData;
    "invoices": Invoice[];
}
```

This is the Invoice class:

```
export class Invoice{
    "id": string;
    "number": string;
    "year": number;
    "date": Date;
    "amount": number;
}
```

Now I want to show a table containing a list of suppliers with the following columns: **id**, **createdAt**, **createdBy**, **totalAmountOfInvoices**, **totalNumberOfInvoices**.

My problem comes with the last two columns which I don't know how to handle properly.

ngx-datatable is expecting a `rows[]` and a `columns[]` in the component, but while I'm passing a `Supplier[]` for the rows, I don't know what I should use for the calculated columns.

What is the best way to display that data? Should I calculate those values and inject them in supplier object  when I retrieve the object in the service, or there's a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Calculate data on server and send as json, or implement deserializer in Angular, or override the constructer, and calc the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Just use the ng-template instead of passing a `column[]` to the table. This way I can call functions in my component.

```
         <ngx-datatable [rows]="supplier" class="material">
            <ngx-datatable-column>
                <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                    <span (click)="sort()">Name</span>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{row.masterData.name}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column>
                <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                    Invoices({{currentYear}})
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{getNumberOfInvoicesCurrentYear(row)}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column>
                <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                    Invoices total amount ({{currentYear}})
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{getNumberOfInvoicesCurrentYear(row)}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ngx-datatable>
```